# CSS Dashboard columns do not float next to eachother

Tags: html, css

So i'm having a problem that is hard  to explain.  Here is the JSFiddle showing the problem :

http://jsfiddle.net/c9cwB/

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.div1 {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
  float: left;
}

.div2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

.div3 {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="container">
      <div class="div1"></div> 
      <div class="div3"></div>
      <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to happen is for the blue box to sit right under the green box so it looks like a website dashboard.

How do I do this? You can change css/html to fix it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c9cwB/4/ - one possible solution...

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to your issue? did my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can float the `.div3` right and add `clear:left;` to the `.div2` to get the desired layout (You can remove the display property as it is of no use combined with floats).

I also simplified your *CSS* code by adding a class to both left divs and using it to style them.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/c9cwB/15/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="div1 left"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>
    <div class="div2 left"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
/* Styles go here */
 #container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
.div1 {
    background: green;
}
.div2 {
    background: blue;
    clear:left;
}
.div3 {
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Check my comment about using `nth-child(even)` to avoid use classes like "left" and "right". Do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: @AndrésTorres well I guess if you have many divs it would be better with `nth-child()` but for only 3 divs, class isn't difficult to maintain + it doesn't change if you add other elements at the same level as the divs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to chage the float on your div3 class.

it should be float: right; instead of float: left;

```
.div3 {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping the ones you want to the left in another layer:

http://jsfiddle.net/dactivo/c9cwB/6/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="div1"></div>    
            <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
    </div>
```

---

```
/* Styles go here */
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
#wrapper{width:50%;  display: inline-block;height:100%;float:left}
.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
  float: left;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;

  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

.div3 {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c9cwB/16/)

```
  <div id="container">
      <div class="div3 right"></div>
      <div class="div1"></div> 
      <div class="div2"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumming that `.widget` is a item/box of the dashboard you can use:

```
.widget {
  float: left;
}

.widget:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/torresandres/pen/wnIxF